# A permanent solution in Visual Studio 2019 to replace this app.manifest.in every project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

My scaling of my monitor is very big, normally 175%, and I now reduced it to 150%.

The result is that the generated forms are much bigger than how they look in the designer.

I found a solution by adding the contents of this app.manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <asmv3:application>
        <asmv3:windowsSettings>
            <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
            <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2</dpiAwareness>
        </asmv3:windowsSettings>
    </asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```

Now I wonder if there isn't another solution than adding every time a manifest file to the project and change the contents to what I wrote above?

Comment: If you go to project settings, Manifest section, and turn on manifest generation then one of the settings is DPI Awareness.  You either need to do that or manually add a manifest to the resource.  Without the DPI Awareness setting API calls are going to lie to you about screen metrics and Windows will scale graphics to match your scaling setting.

Comment: Also, did you mean you changed from 150 to 175?  Using a lower scaling = lower magnification = smaller sizes not larger.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't figure it out. Either I had to embed manifest with settings or chose no manifest and the resource file has .res extinction.

Comment: Sorry Dave S, your solution didn't work for me but thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks wenbingeng-MSFT, I'll keep you in mind if I have other questions.